# Unix programming to subset every 1Mb and name the subset

Tags: unix

I am needing a way to subset a large data set in Unix. I have > 50K SNP, each with the genetic variance they explain and a location (chromosome and position). I need to subset the SNP every 1 million base pairs (position) for each chromosome to create what we call 1Mb windows. I also need to name these windows, for instance *CHR:WINDOW*.

My data is structured as:

```
SNP CHR POS GenVar

BTB-00074935 1 157284336 2.306141e-06
BTB-01512420 8 72495155 1.958865e-06
Hapmap35555-SCAFFOLD20017_21254 18 29600313 1.876211e-06
BTB-01098205 3 68702409 1.222881e-06
ARS-BFGL-NGS-115531 11 74038177 9.597669e-07
ARS-BFGL-NGS-25658 2 119059379 7.953552e-07
BTB-00411452 20 47919708 6.827312e-07
ARS-BFGL-NGS-100532 18 63878550 6.115242e-07
Hapmap60823-rs29019235 1 10717144 5.400144e-07
ARS-BFGL-NGS-42256 10 50282066 4.864838e-07  
.
.
.
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, your key for grouping records into files is (col2, first length-6 digits of col 3)?

Comment: The second portion of the grouping needs to be if the position is 1-1,000,000; 1,000,0001-2,000,000; 2,000,001-3,000,000 and so forth.

Comment: The answer I have given below groups 0-999,999 (as 000), 1,000,000-1,999,999 (as 001), etc. If you need the grouping specified in this comment, then change $3 below to $3-1.

Answer (score 0):

A basic first try, assuming no spaces in any of the first fields (SNP), and that the "key" is (col2, first (length-6) digits of col3):

```
awk '{w=0+substr($3,1,length($3)-6); print >>sprintf("CHR%02d:WINDOW%03d",$2,w)}'
```

This prints to files named like `CHR03:WINDOW456`. If you only wanted something like `03:456` for filenames, edit out the `CHR` and `WINDOW` above.

Also note, subsequent runs will just keep expanding existing files, so you may need a `rm *:*` between runs.